# How to get pixel on QGraphicsPixmapItem on a QGraphicsView from a mouse click

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have a QGraphicsScene with a QGraphicsPixmapItem on it, showing an image. I also have a view showing the scene. I have a mousePressEvent() function defined, looking for mouse clicks on the view.

The view is setup to contain the pixmap:

```
//pixmap is a QGraphicsPixmapItem *
view->fitInView(pixmap, Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

I can get the position of a mouse click in the view's coordinate system:

```
//e is my QMouseEvent *
QPoint local_pt = view->mapFromGlobal(e->globalPos());
```

Now I'd like to map this point to the original image coordinates, using any combination of the QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsPixmapItem

I've tried `pixmap->boundingRect()`, which gives me a QRectF(0,0 778x582), which has the appropriate dimensions (of the original image), but I do not see how the x and y coordinates are related to the local point of the click.

How do I get position of the mouse click in the original image coordinates?

**EDIT:**

This is what ultimately worked:

```
//e is my QMouseEvent *
QPoint  local_pt = view->mapFromGlobal(e->globalPos());
QPointF img_coord_pt = view->mapToScene(local_pt);
```

img_coord_pt is (0,0) when I click the top left corner of the image, and (image width, image height) at the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QGraphicsView::mapToScene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#mapToScene) maps screen coordinates to scene coordinates, then use [QGraphicsView::itemAt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#itemAt) to get the item and [QGraphicsItem::mapFromScene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#mapFromScene) to map scene global coordinates to item local coordinates.

There are inverses of these, of course.

Comment: Thanks. Ultimately what worked was `view->mapToScene(local_pt)`